# Send unicode emoji with PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, unicode, phpmailer, emoji

I'm trying to send unicode emoji trough PHPMailer (5.2) but the emails I sent are received with weird characters instead of emojis.
I'm currently sending HTML emails where I just `echo` a string containing some utf-8 emoji and inspecting the email source the string seems to be printed correctly. For example:

```
echo "";
```

produces:

```
=F0=9F=98=81
```

in the email source code (which should be OK).

Comment: What you're seeing is the quoted-printable transfer encoding, and it's correct, though as you say, you need to tell PHPMailer to use the UTF-8 charset.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turns out that PHPMailer uses charset=iso-8859-1 by default in HTML emails (in the email header you'll find `Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1` while you should use UTF-8: `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`.

You can set the charset in PHPMailer by doing:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to use the slightly different:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
```

Comment: Yes! Was struggling with this really simple thing. I turned to ChatGPT and it didn't flag that even with my full code it asked me to debug and check other things. Great to see that AI isn't taking over just yet.