# Use emoji in dynamic content body of HTML email in PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, phpmailer, emoji

I have been trying to send an HTML email with PHPMailer containing emojis:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
$mail->Subject = "             ";
$mail->Body = "             ";
```

However, the emojis are only displayed correctly in the subject; in the body, they are replaced by question marks (in Thunderbird and Outlook). The email does contain HTML, so just setting `isHTML` to `false` will not suffice. I have looked at [Send unicode emoji with PHPMailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39365797/send-unicode-emoji-with-phpmailer) , but it does not seem to work for me, as the character set is already set to UTF-8. The content is user-generated (the user uses their own mobile keyboard to insert the emoji), so manually replacing every emoji with, for example, an image is not an option. Preferably the solution would be dynamic, so that new emojis also work whenever they come out.

Answer (score 1):

you need to specify emoji's unicode value and try below method.

```
echo json_decode('"\uD83D\uDE00"');
```

Also you can use UTF-8 notation from this [this](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode) table:

example:
 \xF0\x9F\x98\x81 GRINNING FACE WITH SMILING EYES

Comment: That would solve it if I were to write the content myself. However, the input is user-generated. Users just press the smiling face icon on their phone's keyboard, they won't look it up in some table. I am looking for a more dynamic solution, preferably one that will also work when new emojis come out (which is quite frequent).

Comment: @Koenvh sorry but i can't find dynamic word in question and also can you show me how emojieslook like in your backend or html or db  code?

Comment: Well, I did say that the content is user-generated, and because new emojis keep coming out, the dynamic part is kind of a necessity, but I have clarified it anyway. The way the emojis look like is exactly as you see in the example above, as it happens even with a static email body, so uninfluenced by HTML or a database.