# Emoji in email subject line

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Recently I have received newsletters with emojis in the subject line..

I have copy/pasted a subject from the source of a newsletter

```
Subject: =?utf-8?Q?=F0=9F=94=A5=C2=A06=20days=20left=20until=20we=20meet=20you=20at=20TechBBQ=C2=A0=F0=9F=94=A5?=
```

[image]

I use phpmailer to send emails.. How is it possible to reuse the same icons when sending messages?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert Emoji from Unicode in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33547233/how-to-convert-emoji-from-unicode-in-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send unicode emoji with PHPMailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39365797/send-unicode-emoji-with-phpmailer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$subject = "\xF0\x9F\x94\xA5 test \xF0\x9F\x94\xA5";
```

This will put a fire emoji like the above in the beginning and the end of the string when sending with phpmailer. Rememeber to set the encoding in the mail to UTF-8

Comment: Details on how you came to this solution would be appreciated

Comment: https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode